# A single form with multiple workflows

Tags: forms

I'm designing a form to schedule a specific job to run. However, one of the requirements is that the user be able to run the job without scheduling it, and then either abandon the job or continue onto scheduling it.

Specifically, the workflow is:

[image: form flow example]

I'm sort of stumped how to do this elegantly; the results list is a fairly large table (probably taller than the screen), so it either needs to be a scrolling table inside the form, a modal, or a separate page (in which case the flow is weird because it goes p1 -> p2 -> p1). Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Since the Naming&Scheduling is an endpoint and needs to be accessed from two other steps in the flow, I see no harm in putting it in a modal dialog. In that sense it's outside the flow, so the modal won't interrupt, and either you schedule it or you don't.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2NKF4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a sub workflow and have a popup window to handle that. That's probably the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with Koen's answer here but for the sake of keeping things isolated for decision triggers, leave the Schedule button along with the parameters and then once the results are generated and the user is happy with the results you'd use the same workflow as if the user never executed the results to begin with.

Also, are the number of parameters a user can supply for a job a long list or something that falls into a small space on the screen?